# Youtube API REST live stream NO RESULTS

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Im try to get live streaming ID using API REST request. I try using API REST tool from google and im trying manually too and no result and i have an live streaming right now.
This is my channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7Nfr13PyP84jWgU5FS9LGg

This is my api rest solicitude:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC7Nfr13PyP84jWgU5FS9LGg&eventType=live&type=video&key={KEY}
(im using real key)

This is my result: https://prnt.sc/p8qodg

Youtube api tool:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: It's broken for everyone, unfortunately. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048424/youtube-api-search-livestream-stop-to-work/58048537

Comment: I try with this parameter "liveBroadcastContent=live" and i get results but not with "live" stream, just old live streams...