# Youtube API search livestream stop to work

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api

A few days that the youtube api stop to show a livestream videos, is this error only on my api key? if does, is there any other way to find a livestream videos?

I googled if there any message from youtube about this, and i didn't find.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig&eventType=live&type=video&key={MY_API_KEY}

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone.
It's broken for everybody, unfortunately, and it's been this way for over ten days now. As with all Google services, human support and feedback is non-existent, not even an acknowledgement of the issue.

Ref.: https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/14611425

As a workaround, I had to change the logic to use the `q` parameter along with `eventType=live`. This actually works, and, depending on keywords, can also return a whole lot of unrelated live material, which, I think, can be further filtered on the client. This also seems to incur higher quota usage.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I guess the issue is you try to use a meta-channel. UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig refers to what you get when you click on live in the menu, but this only "sums up" what's live, it isn't a real channel itself. Just strip the channelId parameter you should get all active live streams (only tested at reference page https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list but got me 14.5k at time of try).

Matt